# Move text along with notification bar on top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a simple slide up from the bottom notification bar for my page. Everything works perfect as intended, but when I try to make that bar slide down from the top of the page, the behaviour of the text is different. If I make it slide up from the bottom, the text moves along with the div, when sliding down from above, the text appears to stay in place as the div rolls over the text. How can I prevent this from happening?

below is my code to make it pop up from the bottom (the text moves along inside the div), when I make the change to "top: 0" instead of "bottom: 0". The text appears to be in a fixed position from the start.

```js
    $("p").click(function() {  
        $('#message-box').slideToggle('slow').delay(1500).slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

```css
    #message-box {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #FFA339;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #35220C;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index:50;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
    <div id='message-box'>notification</div>
    <p>click here</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - the bar is 50px high, and the text is centered in those 50px thanks to its line-height. That calculation is based off the text's space from the top of the container.

When sliding from the bottom of the screen, the height of the bar is growing from bottom to top. Because the text's position is based off the top of the container, this creates the visual effect of the text sliding "with" the box as the top of the container shifts up, making it look like they're animating together.

When sliding from the top of the screen, the height of the bar is growing from top to bottom. The text doesn't shift because it's always spaced from the top of that container, occupying the same 50px from the top of the screen, so you just see it "reveal".

So, as a fix, I've removed the jQuery animation altogether and showed you how to accomplish this animation using a much smoother CSS transition. Now, by toggling a class with jQuery, the entire bar shifts from off-screen to on-screen, rather than its height changing.

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  $('#message-box').addClass('show').delay(1500).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show').dequeue();
  });
});
```

```css
#message-box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFA339;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #35220C;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .6s;
}

#message-box.show {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='message-box'>notification</div>
<p>click here</p>
```